# VBA: Loop through criteria in an Excel filter?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I've been trying to figure this out all morning. Is there a way to loop through the criteria in a column filter in Excel, while filling an array with the names of the criteria? It seems that filter objects only have a criteria1 and criteria2. Sorry if any of my terminology is unclear, I'm pretty new to Excel.

(this is using Excel 2007)

Comment: hmm I've only got 2010 and 2003. Does 2007 have the multiselect checkbox way of specifying criteria?

Comment: Yeah I think so, if I'm understanding what you mean. It's like a dropdown menu with "Sort from A to Z", some other stuff, and then a bunch of checkboxes beside all the criteria with a "select all" at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that if you have 1 or 2 criteria selected then these will be stored in `.Criteria1` and `.Criteria2`.

However if you have more than 2 then `.Criteria1` becomes an array of the selected filters - which you can then iterate through using...

```
Dim iFilt As Integer       'This should be set equal to the column 
                           'index you are interested in

Dim iFiltCrit as Integer

For iFiltCrit = 1 To UBound( Sheet1.AutoFilter.Filters(iFilt).Criteria1 )
    Debug.Print Sheet1.AutoFilter.Filters(iFilt).Criteria1(iFiltCrit)
Next
```

Note that this only works for a column which has more than 2 criteria - how you determine if that is the case or not is up to you - it's a rather clunky piece of Excel API (surprise surprise) as it is loosely typed.

Comment: So far I haven't been able to get this to work. Here is my code:
    `Dim iFiltCrit As Integer  
    Debug.Print   (UBound(ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(projCol).Criteria1))
    
    For iFiltCrit = 1 To UBound(ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(projCol).Criteria1)
        Debug.Print     (ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(projCol).Criteria1(iFiltCrit))  
    Next  `

The Ubound has a value of 4, but it's giving an error that states "Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object"

Comment: I think you might not be able to use an index on the Criteria1 array, because while that code doesn't work, using a For Each loop seems to.

Comment: Hmm yes I've managed to get that error too. It was working last night! Typical Excel VBA weirdness. Afraid I'm giving up now. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, where I wanted to have a user-defined string for filtering, in which people can give the column and the filtervalue for multiple columns at once.

In this example the string users can define looks like:

"A,foo;B,bar;AD,beyond all recognition" 
Or
"ColumnLetterOrIndex comma FilterValue Semicolon" Repeat.
and so on for any number of columns and values.

Code:

```
Public Function createFilter(filterstring as string) as Variant
Dim tempFilter As Variant
Dim realFilter As Variant

tempfilter = Split(filterstring, ";")
For i = LBound(tempfilter) To UBound(tempfilter)
    ReDim Preserve realFilter(i)
    realFilter(i) = Split(tempfilter(i), ",", 2) 
'The 2 is needed if the filtervalue contains a comma on itself. Otherwise, it can be omitted.
Next i
createFilter = realFilter
End Function
```

The above function will create a multidimensional array from a string of which the values can be used with Excels autofilter from a string. Usage code:

```
Dim userFilter as Variant
userFilter = createFilter(userDefinedFilterString)
For i = LBound(userFilter) To UBound(userFilter)
     'Note that here you'll have to convert the Columnletter to something numeral, unless the users define their column like 1, 2, 3 instead of A, B, C.
     thefiltercolumn = Measure.filter(i)(0)
     .AutoFilter thefiltercolumn, Measure.filter(i)(1)
Next i
```

When the filtervalues are equal to the "Is not equal to" or "contains", you can use excel's built-in way of doing that, e.g.

```
A,<>foo;B,*bar*;AD,>=5
```

Bad part: Multiple criteria on 1 column is not available like in the previous example.